# what is the difference between return redirect('/') and Redirect::to('/')->send(); function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

[First code working. See Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h89l9.png)

[The second code not working. See Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc2LZ.png)

Anyone can help provide the documentation for this code Redirect::to('/')->send();

Comment: Please post code directly, rather than "code image".

Comment: Can you show your route `web.php`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

The `->send()` method should only be used in places where you cannot return a response directly. And even then, it should be used as few times as possible.

Normally, a request will go through a list of middlewares, end up in a controller which will return a response and exit through another list of middlewares. This is the normal way of returning a response.

When you use the `send()` function, you interrupt the pipeline and send the response back immediately.

Now, the reason only `send()` works in your case is because you are redirecting from a constructor and a constructor cannot have a return value. Because of this, the second example will never work.

I would encourage you to use a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware) for this check instead. This way the check is reusable and you can return a redirect response without interrupting the pipeline.